# How to use cookie in Java WatchService?

Tags: java, linux, file, jvm, nio

I'm using `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS` and I'm intended to monitor file system modifications through `WatchService`.

So I have two directories:

- `/home/dir_form`
- `/home/dir_to`

In order to track some file is moved from the directory `dir_from` to `dir_to` I could read from the file descriptor returned by `inotify_init` and in case of `cookie`s of two events with type `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO` are the same we can say that the events are related to each other.

Taking a look at the [***LinuxWatchService.java***](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/solaris/classes/sun/nio/fs/LinuxWatchService.java) sources I found this:

```
private static final int[] offsets             = eventOffsets();
private static final int OFFSETOF_WD           = offsets[0];
private static final int OFFSETOF_MASK         = offsets[1];
private static final int OFFSETOF_LEN          = offsets[3];
private static final int OFFSETOF_NAME         = offsets[4];
```

Where `eventOffsets()` native method is defined in [***LinuxWatchService.c***](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/jdk/file/935758609767/src/solaris/native/sun/nio/fs/LinuxWatchService.c) as follows :

```
JNIEXPORT jintArray JNICALL
Java_sun_nio_fs_LinuxWatchService_eventOffsets(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz)
{
    jintArray result = (*env)->NewIntArray(env, 5);
    if (result != NULL) {
        jint arr[5];
        arr[0] = (jint)offsetof(struct inotify_event, wd);
        arr[1] = (jint)offsetof(struct inotify_event, mask);
        arr[2] = (jint)offsetof(struct inotify_event, cookie);//<--- HERE IS COOKIE
        arr[3] = (jint)offsetof(struct inotify_event, len);
        arr[4] = (jint)offsetof(struct inotify_event, name);
        (*env)->SetIntArrayRegion(env, result, 0, 5, arr);
    }
    return result;
}
```

So as far as I can see, `LinuxWatchService` ignores cookie.

***QUESTION:*** How can I connect `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO` events together and avoid doing the `syscalls` and compare cookie by myself?

Comment: You can't do this in pure Java. You need to implement this yourself or use one of third-party Java wrappers over `inotify`.

Comment: @apangin The java wrapper is what I'm looking for. `LinuxWatchService` from `openjdk` does not seem to provide API for working with cookie. Could you advice something?

Comment: I don't, but quick googling highlighted at least a couple of projects. I'm not sure if they are able to pair `IN_MOVED_FROM` and `IN_MOVED_TO` (probably not, since this requires some application-specific logic), but it does not look like a difficult task to match two events by an `int` identifier.